# View Time Machine backup drive on Windows 7

Tags: time-machine, windows, disk-format

I use an external hard drive to regularly backup my Mac using Time Machine. However, I wanted to copy the data on this drive to a Windows 7 machine which does not work. It seems, that the PC recognices the external dirve, but does not list it.

Is it even possible to run the hard drive on a PC? I suggest this might be due to the formation. Is there a way to overcome this problem without re-formatting the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read HFS+ disks on Windows by installing Apple's Boot Camp drivers:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638

Answer (score 1):

You can access an OSX formatted disk using 3d part applications such

[HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html) or [Macdrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Boot Camp drivers don't support every machine - mine, for instance, a Razer Blade 14" 2014 running Windows 10, wasn't supported. I found HFSExplorer to be a somewhat clunky but still good solution. (It's GNU, too!)